# insert icons to text messages with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, cordova

I have angularjs phonegap application with backend on nodejs.
I have a simple chat page with input for text of message, but user can choose a smile picture from list and put it among text. I didn't find any solutions for my questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use emoji icons with angularjs, you could use angular-emoji-filter module: https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter.

Comment: thx for answer, but I need to insert smileys from pictures. so I have a list of urls, like http://example.com/sticker1.png and i need to insert picture, which will choose user to his massage

Comment: do you have experience with using this plugin?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately not.